# zsh: command not found: ssh -T git@github.com

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, zsh

I'm having trouble attempting to ssh to GitHub following their guide:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

When I run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: ssh -T git@github.com
```

I'm running:

- macOS 12.3.1
- Default login shell (zsh)
- [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh) (also tried without)
- `echo $PATH`
- `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

Steps to reproduce:

- `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@email.com"`
- Hit Enter after “Enter file”
- Hit Enter twice after “Enter passphrase”
- `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`
- Added the new SSH key to https://github.com/settings/keys
- Attempted to ssh to GitHub
- `ssh -T git@github.com`
- Get the error
- `zsh: command not found: ssh -T git@github.com`

[image]

Switching my shell to bash fixes this problem, but I'd prefer to stay on zsh.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `whereis ssh`? What happens if you just use the command `ssh` (in `zsh`) without any arguments?

Comment: For some reason, `ssh -T git@github.com` is interpreted as one argument. Did you copy the command into the question, or did you retype it? If it is exactly as you posted (i.e. no weird things that look like spaces but aren't), it's very strange. What does `type ssh` say?

Comment: Thank you @Amadan! Typing it by hand did the trick (I had copied and pasted from the GitHub guide). If you answer the question I'll be happy to mark as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that this is one of those cases (they are common!) where a screen-shot *discards the actual problem*, which is that what looks like a space, is not a space. That's one of the reasons for the "don't use screenshots if at all possible" bits of advice in the [ask] guidelines.

Comment: @Ryan : With this type of problems, you can easily see what you have actually copied by pasting the command into i.e. `xxd` and check the hexadecimal output.

Comment: After saving the ssh command in my MacBook Notepad, there was a bug that invisible space special characters were included when pasting it.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `ssh -T git@github.com` was interpreted as one word, probably due to the space character not being an actual space character. Unicode table of confusables lists as many as 18 characters that look like space (U+0020) but are not.